# image not getting displayed even after converting to base64

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, blob

I am retrieving a blob image from a database then converting it to base64 in ruby. The code looks like this

```
            value = FbxLauncher::Image.get_image_data(re["TYPE_VALUE"])
            value = Base64.encode64(value)
            str = "{image}"
```

After that i am replacing "value" for "{image}" like this

```
        <img src= "data:image/jpg;base64, {image}" 
        style="margin-left: 5px;margin-top: -18px;height: 72px;width: 100px;">
```

But the image is not getting displayed. When I inspect element in console I get the following data

```
        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,"ivborw0kggoaaaansuheugaaag4aaabicaiaaacyzfehaaagaeleqvr4xu18=""  c7bd11nefqz93vucc89962vllizltii="" 5tyiq50qqkozeklspa8mteopthrk="" xwykux5tiir2crqlndozujpiticedqraarish5jyjl+yzemwrq50dv="" nfc5+=""....(continued)
```

What is the significance of this string format some_string ="" in img tag?

Comment: How are you replacing "{image}" with value?  It almost looks like you have created a hash with  all the some_string="" in your output.

Comment: like this ad_struc = ad_struc.gsub(str,value)

Comment: What are the contents of value before you call encode64, can you show the output of running FbxLauncher::Image.get_image_data(re["TYPE_VALUE"]) in irb?  My guess is it's not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using Base64.strict_encode64 and not Base64.encode64.  Encode64 inserts linefeed characters, which seem to be affecting your output somehow.